# Calculate power/ force of swipe

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bulletphysics

I'm making a user interactive wheel using javascript and html5 canvas that when swiped would spin the wheel. However I'm trying to work on the "force/ power" of the swipe

What is a good formula to calculate this?

Comment: Why not measure _distance^2 = x^2 + y^2_ where _x, y_ is the movement of "cursor" in a certain (small) time during your swipe?

Comment: I'm using
    dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(( _x1 - _x2), 2) + Math.pow((_y1 - _y2), 2));
    speed = dist/ (gettime() - time); // start of swipe - end of swipe time
    power = Math.abs((1.5 * angle) * speed); // I'm not sure about this part
    targetAngle = (power * 360); // estimated amount of revs

Comment: I'm getting an odd reading sometimes as I find myself swiping in a circular motion...

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a solution:

```
var deltaX = CENTER_OF_CANVAS_WIDTH - Mouse.x;
var deltaY = CENTER_OF_CANVAS_HEIGHT - Mouse.y;
var angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

`angle` will give you the angle in radians of the X axis of the vector created between those two points. Long story short, it will let you drag in a circular motion and give you the results you expect.

Rotation in canvas is in radians, so this should be good to go, but if you need to convert this to degrees you can do:

```
var degrees = angle * (180 / Math.PI);
```

The rest of your equation for velocity is correct, just use the difference in angle instead of distance.

Comment: hmmm i was using this
`angle = function direction(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) { return Math.atan2(_y2 - _y1, _x2 - _x1) * RAD_2_DEG; }` to get the angles from the center but when i

`speed = end.angle - start.angle / ((end.time - start.time) / 1000);
     if( Math.abs(end.angle - start.angle) > 180) speed = speed * -1;` The direction of the spin is pretty screwed up depending on how i swipe


P.S. i calculate in degrees then convert to radians when drawing for canvas

Comment: In other words it goes anti - clockwise i need it to go clockwise

Comment: Can you put what you have in a jsfiddle and I'll take a look?